# Twitter Bootstrap carousel indicators triggered animation doesn't work properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm having a problem with Bootstrap carousel. I've created one, and when I use arrows (carousel-control) it works like a charm, but when I'm using carousel-indicators to navigate through slides just slides current slide to the position without animating other slides. My container becomes clear white and then I see slide moving for a side.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
<div id="main-events" class="carousel slide">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#main-events" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#main-events" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">

                      <div class="item active">
                        <img width="540px" src="/media/banners/foo.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h4>title1</h4><br/>
                          <p>some text</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="item ">
                        <img width="540px" src="/media/banners/vi.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h4>title2</h4><br/>
                          <p>some text</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>

              </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#main-events" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#main-events" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Code is Correct..
In my system this code working fine..

There is no definition for  class "slide" in Bootstrap 3..But without "Slide" class ,carousel images will change with out any animation effect..

Add this script in you code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    });
</script>
```

Check the Bootstrap CSS & JS Reference in you code..
and also check the order of the Reference files

**You can follow this order:-**

1. bootstrap.css
2. bootstrap-theme.css
3. jquery-1.9.1.js
4. bootstrap.js

The script block will not work with out JQ Library..So add JQ Library file correctly ..

And Ensure that the JQ file loaded before the script working..For that you can add the reference at the top of your page

[Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)